# How to get the width and height of a masked area

Tags: apache-flex

I am loading an external swf using the SWFLoader component. The swf that is being loaded is masked so that only a portion is being shown. However, when it's loaded the actual size of the swf (loader.content.width/loader.content.height) is the complete swf including the masked area. Therefore, the loaded swf does not display properly in the itemrenderer Is there a way to to grab the size of the just the masked area as opposed to getting the size of the entire swf's contents? also i need to re size the masked area

Answer (score 0):

By default, the width and height properties always refer to the boundaries of your object, regardless of its visibility.

You can override the getters for height and width in the loaded SWF's document class to return the mask size:

```
override public function get height () : Number {
    return myMask.height;
}

override public function get width () : Number {
    return myMask.width;
}
```

or use bitmap drawing to find the actual visible boundaries of the object, pretty much the same way it is done in [this useful tutorial](http://old.troygilbert.com/2007/06/pixel-perfect-collision-detection-in-actionscript3/) on more exact collision detection (just skip the part about combining two bitmaps and only use the color detection).

Comment: Troy Gilbert's tutorial link is no longer found.